# Kernel Development: how to identify the cache events (hit/miss/TLB/L1/L2) on some particular kernel code?

Tags: linux, caching, linux-kernel, tlb

For example: if we are trying to `memcpy()` 10,20,30 bytes sequentially, then are we able to trace which cache events like hit/miss/TLB/L1/L2, via the
*difference b/w cache hits before* and *hits after* calling `memcpy()`.

I'm using a perf tool to analyze the performance counter for cache events, but for this I'd need to pass the command, for example:

```
perf stat -e L1-dcache-loads <commands>
```

Any idea on how to proceed?